# Google Drive API: The provided file ID is not usable

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

What rules should I follow to set custom ID for File? I tried short "12345", "abcde", 44-character alphanumeric string, UUID.randomUUID().toString() (with/without dashes) - all attempts return "The provided file ID is not usable". I could not find any documented requirements. The code:

```
Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credentials).build();
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/png", tempFile);
File body = new File();
body.setId(...);
body.setTitle(...);
body.setMimeType("image/png");
File result = drive.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
```

The response:

```
400 Bad Request
{
    "code": 400,
    "errors":
    [{
        "domain": "global",
        "location": "file.id",
        "locationType": "other",
        "message": "The provided file ID is not usable",
        "reason": "invalid"
    }],
    "message": "The provided file ID is not usable"
}
```

The same code correctly uploads my file to Drive when I am **not** trying to set ID.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the id, but you have to use a pre-generated id given to you by Google.
I had the same problem, so I dove into the javadoc, and stumbled upon the GeneratedIds Class. Here's the code that works for me:

```
    int numOfIds = 20;
    GeneratedIds allIds = null;
    try {
        allIds = driveService.files().generateIds()
                .setSpace("drive").setCount(numOfIds).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<String> generatedFileIds = allIds.getIds();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The answer gives information which should be available here in the Drive REST API guide: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#uploading_using_a_pregenerated_id

Answer (score 2):

You don't set the the ID, it is assigned by Google Drive at creation. The ID you are talking about is the string you see when you go to *drive.google.com*, right-click an object (folder/file), and select 'Get link'. You get something like:

> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1blahblahblahblahfdR25i

and the string '**0B1blahblahblahblahfdR25i**' is the ID.

Test it. Get it from your *drive.google.com*, go to the [bottom this page - TryIt!](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get), paste the *0B1blahblahblahblahfdR25i* into the *fileId* field.

Back to your problem. You are apparently trying to create a file, try this:

```
com.google.api.services.drive.Drive mGOOSvc:
...
/**************************************************************************
   * create file in GOODrive
   * @param prnId  parent's ID, (null or "root") for root
   * @param titl  file name
   * @param mime  file mime type
   * @param file  file (with content) to create
   * @return      file id  / null on fail
   */
  static String createFile(String prnId, String titl, String mime, java.io.File file) {
    String rsId = null;
    if (mGOOSvc != null && mConnected && titl != null && mime != null && file != null) try {
      File meta = new File();
      meta.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(prnId == null ? "root" : prnId)));
      meta.setTitle(titl);
      meta.setMimeType(mime);

      File gFl = mGOOSvc.files().insert(meta, new FileContent(mime, file)).execute();
      if (gFl != null)
        rsId = gFl.getId();
    } catch (Exception e) { UT.le(e); }
    return rsId;  
  }
```

The return, the ***rsId*** is the ID you're looking for.

It is taken from an [Android demo here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/restdemo/REST.java) (to explain the context), but the Api calls there should be pretty much the same. You can actually pull some CRUD primitives out of there.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks! But are you sure I can't set the custom ID? Then why is File.setId() method public? I definitely can set custom IDs for events in Google Calendar API so I thought I can do the same in Drive API.

Comment: Not sure, but I've never heard of it. I've always took for granted that it is the RESULT of creation. You create object by supplying METADATA and CONTENT and get it's ID. And use that ID later for any reference to a Goo object (folder, file). READ, UPDATE, TRASH/DELETE.  See the primitives in the REST.java I pointed to.

Comment: Thinking about it, I'm almost sure you can't supply your own. It is UNIQUE in the Goo universe (and probably the entire universe), so they can't let you or me mess with it.

Comment: Google Calendar event ID must be unique as well but you can set your own (following the documented rules of course). And same question remains - why does the setId() method exist and is public.

Comment: see "new ParentReference().setId()..." in the code above

Comment: Thanks again! Your code has ParentReference.setId(), not File.setId() even though these classes has same parent. Probably you are right and I just can't set custom ID for the new files but I would like to hear confirmation from the Drive developers and/or see this fact documented.

Comment: If you check the [Files resource representation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource) `id` is not listed as writable.

Comment: Actually, you _can_ set the ID, if you use values created by the **generateIds** service (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/generateIds). You cannot set arbitrary IDs unfortunately, even if they were UUIDs. You'll get "The provided file ID is not usable" if you try.